# Jenkins requests node > 10 when running newman eventhough it runs fine con command line

Tags: jenkins, newman

I've installed jenkins and newman on a azure virtual machine to execute Postman test cases. When I ran the tests through command line it works like a charm, but if I try to run it as a jenkins job I got the next error message:

newman run postmantest.json

newman: required node version >=10

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

I need to know why it sends an error message eventhough I have node 15+ installed on the machine and why it is not using that version.

thanks in advance!